# why i am getting a error while using json with discord.py

Tags: json, discord.py

Hi i am trying to add a money system in my discord.py. i am using json with it. i am following a tutorial on youtube. bot and i am trying this code:

```
@client.command()
async def bal(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    users = await get_bank_data()
    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance")
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "Bank", value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
    



async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0
    with open("mainBank.json", "r") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True



async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainBank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
```

but i am getting a error:

```
Ignoring exception in command bal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\saheb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/saheb/Documents/Discord Bot/DiscordBot.py", line 49, in bal
    await open_account(ctx.author)
  File "c:/Users/saheb/Documents/Discord Bot/DiscordBot.py", line 84, in open_account
    json.dump(users, f)
  File "C:\Users\saheb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 180, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

please help if you know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open files in the write mode to write to them (`json.dumps` writes to a file), you can open a file by doing `open("filename", "w")`, the `"w"` says to open in write mode.

Answer (score -1):

Because you use `with open("mainBank.json", "r") as f:`. That `'r'` means just **read**. If you just want to append new values, use `'a'`, if you want to read and write, use `'r+'`.

Comment: now this error is coming: `Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Is your json file empty?

Comment: yes, means i want that its automatically creates a space for a user who uses that command.